# Apply as.numeric on a list of data.frames

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, lapply

Currently I'm learning to use R for simple financial calculations.
I have seven data frames and I'm trying to apply the same function to all of them.
The vector names are the same for all dfs starting with "Date" and are initially "chars". I managed to convert every "Date" vector to the date format with:

```
listOf <- c(Invesco2, Lyxor1, Lyxor2, ComStage, Ossiam, SPDR, Vanguard) # list of dfs
for (i in listOf){
  i[1] <- as.Date(i[1], "%d-%m-%y")
}
```

Now I'm trying to change the rest of vectors to numeric with again a for loop and "lapply":

```
lapply(listOf, as.numeric)
```

The console just prints all the vectors and gives 37 errors:
"In lapply(listOf, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion"

```
for (i in listOf){
  i <- as.numeric(i)
}
```

Again 37 Errors:  In as.numeric(i) : NAs introduced by coercion
In both cases nothing changed.
Pls help

EDIT:
There is a sample a the data set:

```
# Create the sample vectors
Date <- c("23-01-19", "24-01-19", "25-01-19", "26-01-19", "27-01-19" )
Open <- c("69.849998", "69.440002", "69.540001", "70.32", "69.559998")
High <- c("69.849998", "69.440002", "69.540001", "70.32", "69.559998")
Low <- c("69.849998", "69.440002", "69.540001", "70.32", "69.559998")
Close <- c("69.849998", "69.440002", "69.540001", "70.32", "69.559998")
Adj_Close <- c("69.849998", "69.440002", "69.540001", "70.32", "69.559998")
Volume <- c("0", "0", "0", "0","0")

# Create df
InvescoDf <- data.frame(Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Adj_Close, Volume)

# Create another df
OssiamDf <- InvescoDf

# Put in list together
new_list <- list(InvescoDf, OssiamDf)
```

EDIT 2:
It creates factors. In the orginal data the vectors are chars.

EDIT 3:

```
  Date     Open      High      Low       Close     `Adj Close` Volume
  <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>       <chr> 
1 23-01-19 69.849998 69.849998 69.849998 69.849998 69.849998   0     
2 24-01-19 69.440002 69.440002 69.440002 69.440002 69.440002   0     
3 25-01-19 69.540001 69.540001 69.540001 69.540001 69.540001   0     
4 28-01-19 70.32     70.32     70.32     70.32     70.32       0     
5 29-01-19 69.559998 69.559998 69.559998 69.559998 69.559998   0     
6 30-01-19 69.580002 69.580002 69.580002 69.580002 69.580002   0
```

BR
Toni

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are creating a `list`, use

```
listOf <- list(Invesco2, Lyxor1, Lyxor2, ComStage, Ossiam, SPDR, Vanguard)
```

Each data.frame inside the `list` is also a `list` with columns of equal length and `as.numeric` can be applied to vectors.  So, we need to loop over the `data.frame` inside the `list` i.e a double `lapply` is needed

```
new_list <- lapply(new_list, function(dat) {
            dat[[1]] <- as.Date(dat[[1]], "%d-%m-%y")
            dat[-1] <- lapply(dat[-1],  function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
            dat
      })
str(new_list)
#List of 2
# $ :'data.frame':  5 obs. of  7 variables:
#  ..$ Date     : Date[1:5], format: "2019-01-23" "2019-01-24" "2019-01-25" "2019-01-26" ...
#  ..$ Open     : num [1:5] 69.8 69.4 69.5 70.3 69.6
#  ..$ High     : num [1:5] 69.8 69.4 69.5 70.3 69.6
#  ..$ Low      : num [1:5] 69.8 69.4 69.5 70.3 69.6
#  ..$ Close    : num [1:5] 69.8 69.4 69.5 70.3 69.6
#  ..$ Adj_Close: num [1:5] 69.8 69.4 69.5 70.3 69.6
#  ..$ Volume   : num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
# $ :'data.frame':  5 obs. of  7 variables:
#  ..$ Date     : Date[1:5], format: "2019-01-23" "2019-01-24" "2019-01-25" "2019-01-26" ...
#  ..$ Open     : num [1:5] 69.8 69.4 69.5 70.3 69.6
#  ..$ High     : num [1:5] 69.8 69.4 69.5 70.3 69.6
#  ..$ Low      : num [1:5] 69.8 69.4 69.5 70.3 69.6
#  ..$ Close    : num [1:5] 69.8 69.4 69.5 70.3 69.6
#  ..$ Adj_Close: num [1:5] 69.8 69.4 69.5 70.3 69.6
#  ..$ Volume   : num [1:5] 0 0 0 0 0
```

Or another option is

```
new_list <- lapply(new_list,  function(dat) {
                  dat <- type.convert(dat, as.is = TRUE)
                  dat[[1]] <- as.Date(dat[[1]], "%d-%m-%y")
                  dat
                })
names(new_list) <- c('InvescoDf', 'OssiamDf')
list2env(new_list, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you akrun for the quick reply. I understand why I need to use the double loop, unfortunatly it doesn't work though if I copy it in. I also changed the to "list" as you said...And I just saw that my function to transform to date format didn't work from the beginning on.

Comment: @ToniR Please use a small reproducible example as I don't know which column you are changing to Date and others to numeric

Comment: @ToniR  In your code, you are changing the first column to `Date`.  If that is the case, I updated my post

Comment: I added a sample df. The function still doesn't work for me. And yes, I'm trying to change the data type of the first column to date und the others to numbers.

Comment: @ToniR Without a small reproducible example with `dput`, it is difficult to know what exactly the issue.  I am using the code based on the description and it works for me

Comment: @ToniR you have all `factor` variables.  It needs either `as.numeric(as.character` or just `type.convert`

Comment: It indeed works if do `str(new_list)` even for the original data. But if I do `str(InvescoDf)` or `str(Invesco2)` in the original data it is still the same..

Comment: @ToniR I would suggest to keep  it in a list instead of updating the original data frame objects

Comment: @ToniR I updated the code with `list2env` (but not recommended)

Comment: I applied this answer to a similar issue, but didn't have a date column first so just wanted them all numeric: list_dfs <- lapply(list_dfs, (x) x <- lapply(x, (y) as.numeric(as.character(y)))) Mine were also double (not sure why) so ran list_dfs <- lapply(list_dfs, as.data.frame)

Comment: @The_Tams have you returned the `x` (or here it is the `dat`) as i showed in the post

Comment: @akrun I am sorry I am not sure what you mean. I found this answer when looking to make all my columns numeric in a list of dataframes I had made out of an array. The first two were factors, and third already numeric. The full code is below so if its not there, I didn't do it (sorry its a bit messy in a comment)
dims <- c(1:12)
cadfs <- lapply(dims, \(i) (as.data.frame(as.table(ca[,,i]))))
colnames <- c("lon", "lat", "CldAm")
cadfs <- lapply(cadfs, setNames, colnames)
cadfs <- lapply(cadfs, \(x) x <- lapply(x, \(y) as.numeric(as.character(y))))
cadfs <- lapply(cadfs, as.data.frame)

Answer (score -1):

Here is another option. This takes the list, converts the date to date, then converts anything that is character to numeric across the list of dataframes.

```
library(tidyverse)

new_list %>%
  map(., 
         ~mutate(.x, Date = lubridate::dmy(Date)) %>%
           mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric)
      )
#> [[1]]
#>         Date  Open  High   Low Close Adj_Close Volume
#> 1 2019-01-23 69.85 69.85 69.85 69.85     69.85      0
#> 2 2019-01-24 69.44 69.44 69.44 69.44     69.44      0
#> 3 2019-01-25 69.54 69.54 69.54 69.54     69.54      0
#> 4 2019-01-26 70.32 70.32 70.32 70.32     70.32      0
#> 5 2019-01-27 69.56 69.56 69.56 69.56     69.56      0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>         Date  Open  High   Low Close Adj_Close Volume
#> 1 2019-01-23 69.85 69.85 69.85 69.85     69.85      0
#> 2 2019-01-24 69.44 69.44 69.44 69.44     69.44      0
#> 3 2019-01-25 69.54 69.54 69.54 69.54     69.54      0
#> 4 2019-01-26 70.32 70.32 70.32 70.32     70.32      0
#> 5 2019-01-27 69.56 69.56 69.56 69.56     69.56      0
```